# how to copy docker images from nexus docker repo to aws ecr in jenkins pipeline

Tags: nexus, amazon-ecr

I have requirement to copy all nexus images to aws ece but not sure how to do it
how to copy docker images from nexus docker repo to aws ecr in jenkins pipeline

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the easiest option would be to pull the image from the nexus , retag and push.

Let's say you have docker-nexus.example.com as your docker nexus repo.
The AWS ECR has it's own unique DNS which can't be hidden behind DNS unless with NGINX proxy and even there i read are some issues but for easier understanding let's call it a docker-ecr.aws.amazon.com
And use the docker tag SOURCE_IMAGE[:TAG] TARGET_IMAGE[:TAG]

So what you would do is

docker pull docker-nexus.example.com/application1:version1
docker tag docker-nexus.example.com/application1:version1 docker-ecr.aws.amazon.com/application1:version1
docker push docker-ecr.aws.amazon.com/application1:version1

And repeat cross all images.